# Automatically pass a class by value or by reference depending on its size

Tags: c++, type-conversion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have this class which I want to pass around Windows as LPARAM parameter. Since it's small enough to fit inside LPARAM I want to pass it by value, but in case it expands later I want it to automatically switch to passing by reference.

<s>I would use something like</s>

`typedef boost::call_traits<CMyClass>::param_type CMyClassParam;`

which should be either `const CMyClass` or `const CMyClass&`
depending on whether `sizeof(CMyClass) <= sizeof(LPARAM)`
but call_traits optimizes only small PODs, not small classes.

typedef is taken care of by advice of Anycorn:
`typedef boost::mpl::if_c<(sizeof(CMyClass) <= sizeof(LPARAM)), CMyClass, CMyClass&>::type CMyClassParam;`

And then, how do I convert between CMyClassParam and LPARAM
(in case you don't know, LPARAM is int, long enough to store a pointer)

```
CMyClass::operator LPARAM()
{
    // must be either
    return *(LPARAM*)this;
    //or
    return reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this);
}
    //so that I may call:

void SomeWinFunc(LPARAM p);

CMyClass vi;
SomeWinFunc(vi);

// and then get it back:
void SomeWinCallback(LPARAM p)
{
    CMyClassParam vi = (?????)p;
    // which should translate into either
    CMyClass ti = *(CMyClass*)(&p); // make a bitwise copy
    // or
    CMyClass& ti = *(CMYClass*)p;
}
```

Comment: just write your own traits class. however, this appears to be a clear case of premature optimization. google what knuth said about that.

Comment: In the most general usage of C++, you can't pack a `struct` into an `int` because the machine may have integral throwing NaNs that cause an exception just by copying the value. More practically, this will probably work but violates strict aliasing rules as written… unfortunately I don't know if I can help with those rules…

Comment: It's a matter of passing local objects by value out of the function scope vs. creating them on the heap and implementing some garbage collector to keep track and dispose of them. This is the task that I'd like to optimize away (or defer until I absolutely have to).

Comment: @panda-34 passing the struct by value still degrades gracefully. Two machine words in registers/stack aren't catastrophically slower than one.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Where do I put these two words? (dwords, actually) I'm given one int and that's all I'll ever get from windows. Whatever I have I must cram into it.

Comment: @panda-34 Sorry, I assumed you were passing to your own functions.

Comment: @panda - Adding some machinery just in case it might be needed later isn't very agile. Pass a pointer if you expect the struct to grow later, pass by value if it is a simple value. Done.

Comment: @Bo Persson Actually, it's the other way around. Adding the ability to pass pointers would involve creating a lot of machinery which wouldn't be very agile in case I never need it. As it is I'm only adding a couple of typedefs to save myself the possible trouble of changing a hundred declarations if need be. I prefer spending an hour on learning some metaprogramming techniques to spending 10 minutes on a search-and-replace operaton.

Comment: @Panda - OK, let me rephrase my advice: If you absolutely, positively know that a particular struct is always going to be the size of an int, and you believe this is important, pass it by value. Otherwise, don't. This is never ever going to be a performance bottleneck in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
typedef typename mpl::if_c<(sizeof(T) <= MAX), T, T&>::type P;
P param = p;
```

but I'd think compiler would optimize this for you automagically

Comment: This metafunction has been standardized as `std::conditional`.

Comment: Since C++0x became C++11 over a year ago, it has been *the* C++.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : True, but then, how many compilers already implement that? And then, are you sure the user have access to that compiler? I'd be happy to have the two solutions, that is `mpl::if_c` and `std::conditional`, because then I have an answer no matter the generation of the compiler I'm using.

Comment: @paercebal Yes, this is the info I've provided… substitute `std::conditional` for `mpl::if_c` to translate it to C++11.